# How to retrieve inputs provided by user from input field in R Shiny Application?

Tags: r, shiny-server

My question is that I have given a input field where user can give its input and I can retrieve the input provided by the user to process further.

In server.R file what I am doing is given below that is taking value entered by user in the keyword variable.Now when I am calling keyword() its giving me an error:
keyword<- reactive ({ input$text })
some_tweets<- search Twitter(keyword(),n=100,lang="en")

> Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried
>   to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive
>   expression or observer.)

What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Why not just use input$text as is, why reassign it to keyword?

Comment: I have done that to but its giving the same error. Its not allowing me to read the input text from input field.It should be in reactive/observer.